# How to use dynamic values in Interval in Spark SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A working Spark SQL:

```sql
SELECT current_timestamp() - INTERVAL 10 DAYS as diff from sample_table
```

The Spark SQL I tried (non-working):

```sql
SELECT current_timestamp() - INTERVAL col1 DAYS as diff from sample_table
```

The error gotten from the above query:

```
mismatched input 'DAYS' expecting 

== SQL ==
SELECT current_timestamp() - INTERVAL col1 DAYS as diff from sample_table
------------------------------------------^^^
" Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in call answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: "
mismatched input 'DAYS' expecting 

== SQL ==
SELECT current_timestamp() - INTERVAL col1 DAYS as diff from sample_table
------------------------------------------^^^
```

I want to use `col1` as a dynamic interval value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is data type `col1` ? is possible to add sample data

Answer (score 4):

SparkSQL function [make_interval](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#make_interval) achieves this:

```
SELECT current_timestamp() - make_interval(0, 0, 0, col1, 0, 0, 0) as diff from sample_table
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I had a `Date` that I needed to a hours from another column to. It was necessary to cast the `Date` to a `Timestamp` to add hours to it.

Comment: How to do it before Spark 3.0